# Getting Unnotarized Developer ID

Tags: app-store, electron-builder, codesign, mac-app-store, apple-developer

I'm having issues signing my electron mac app.
I'm trying to upload the pkg to MacStore, but I get rejected by them as the software appears to be done by an unknown developer.

I have my Developer Id Certificate and everything (I guess) is required.

After building and notarizing my app (I received the confirmation from Apple that the notarizing was successful I get the following information when running those commands:

```
codesign -dvv dist/mas/app-1.1.9.pkg
Executable=/Users/user/Documents/Development/app/electron-app/dist/mas/App-1.1.9.pkg
Identifier=MyCompany-1
Format=generic
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=172 flags=0x10000(runtime) hashes=1+2 location=embedded
Signature size=9059
Authority=Developer ID Application: MyCompany Inc (xxxxxxxx)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=23 Dec 2021 09:43:58
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=xxxxxxx
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=172


spctl -vvv --assess --type exec dist/mas/electron-app-1.1.9.pkg
dist/mas/electron-app-1.1.9.pkg: rejected
source=Unnotarized Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: MyCompany Inc (xxxxxx)

pkgutil --check-signature dist/mas/app-1.1.9.pkg
Package "app-1.1.9.pkg":
   Status: signed by a developer certificate issued by Apple (Development)



Certificate Chain:
    1. 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: MyCompany Inc (xxxxxx)
       Expires: 2022-12-06 02:39:58 +0000
   
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
   Expires: 2030-02-20 00:00:00 +0000
   
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Apple Root CA
   Expires: 2035-02-09 21:40:36 +0000
```

Any clue where the issue could be?